# The extent to which one is, or the state of being, of or pertaining to turtles/tortoises

Tags: vocabulary

I'm having trouble finding a word which fits. I did a google search for testudineousness and testudinateness, but sadly had no hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have tried to apply the same rule as seen in words like "bovine", "feline", etc, but with the latin for the tortoise family, which is "testudo".  I'd expect the word generated from this process to be ***"testudine"***, not the words you list.

This does appear to exist as a word:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Testudine

Strictly speaking this means "of the order Testudo", but, like "feline" or "bovine", and many other similar examples, the meaning could cross over into an adjective used to describe characteristics of other things (eg people).

So, if you were jogging with someone, and you were much faster than them, you could say *"Your testudine pace is way too slow for me!"*.  Whether they would know what you were talking about is a different matter.

Comment: But OP appears to be seeking a noun--presumably testudinity.

Comment: StoneyB is indeed correct, a noun for either "the state of being testudine" or "the extent to which one is testudine" is what I'm looking for.

'Testudinity' is appealing, but I contend that 'testudine' means what Max Williams claims it does - the link provided only mentions the 'order Testudines', and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/testudines this also suggests that it's simply the name of the family (or a member of said family, in the case that it is used in the singular).

Comment: @StoneyB in that case i would look to see what the equivalent for more well-known examples (like feline) is, which is "felinity", so i think "testudinity" is a good choice.

Comment: Ah sorry, looks like I completely missed the third paragraph somehow.

Comment: @frugs regarding the definition:  it's possible that the word "testudine", meaning "tortoise-like" hasn't been used enough (if at all) to make it into the dictionary.  However, it is still the right word for its meaning: you could legitimately start using it and if anyone asks, you could explain, saying "it's like feline, you know, but for tortoises rather than cats".

Comment: @frugs *Testudines* is merely a taxonomic use of the plural of L *testudo*, 'tortoise', a word with other figurative uses in English: a type of tumor, a type of armored siege engine, and a type of lute.

Comment: @StoneyB This is slightly off-topic, but those usages sound interesting; do you mind providing a link? :)

Comment: Samuel Johnson two adjectives: 
TESTU'DINATED. (arched) TESTUDI'NEOUS (of the shell)

Comment: @frugs [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt209murruoft#page/226/mode/2up), s.v. 'testudo'.